# is "ubuntu netbook remix" and "intel moblin os" built up from the same base?

Tags: ubuntu, embedded

i have been debating which OS to use for a car pc.. and ubuntu netbook remix (UNR) and moblin seem to be the best ones suited for a small touch screen..

however, i want to use an OS which has good support from the community.. and was confused upon reading the wikis for each of them which says that both OSes are built by canonical..

can anyone please let me know if both these OSes have the same ubuntu base ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] both these OSes have the same ubuntu base ??

No.

[Moblin](http://moblin.org/documentation/moblin-distro-developers-guide/moblin-infrastructure) is produced by the Linux Foundation and is NOT based on Ubuntu.

[Ubuntu Netbook Remix (UNR)](http://www.canonical.com/projects/ubuntu/unr) is produced by Canonical and based on Ubuntu. It is NOT based on Moblin but it contains a few optimizations taken from Moblin.

However, a third product called [Ubuntu Moblin Remix](http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2009/10/pygmy-portable-dell-mini-10v-with-the-ubuntu-moblin-remix.ars/2) is produced by Canonical and Dell, it is based on both Ubuntu and Moblin. If I understood well, is is mostly Ubuntu's core components and package system with Moblin' user interface.

All three are different OSes.